# How to re-declare a variable in the same scope in perl?

Tags: perl, scope, warnings, declaration, variable-declaration

Is there a way to re-declare a variable in the same scope using the `my` keyword in perl? When I run the following script:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $var = 3;
print "$var\n";

undef $var;
my $var = 4;
print "$var\n";
```

I get the "desired" output, but there is also a warning `"my" variable $var masks earlier declaration in same scope`. Is there a way to re-declare the variable without getting the warning?

I'm not sure, but I think this is because `my` happens at compile-time and `undef` happens at run-time because the warning is being printed even before the first `print` statement. (I'm not even sure if perl actually compiles the thing before running it.)

**Context:** I want to be able to copy a chunk of code and paste it multiple times in the same file without having to edit-out all the `my` declarations. I guess this isn't the best way to do it, but any solution to the problem would be appreciated.

Comment: You do not need to use "my" second time. You need to declare it with "my" once. After that you can assing new values to it at any point without redelairing it.

Comment: You do not need undef $var; either.

Comment: If you're copying the code multiple times, maybe you should make the code into a subroutine and call it multiple times instead?

Comment: @ChrisTurner, that's a good idea, but there are some variables outside this copied chunk that are accessed in the chunk. I guess I should declare those using `our` or `local` to access them in the subroutine if I were to go this way.

Comment: the trick is to figure out what variables you need inside the function or subroutine. you can pass all those variables from your main part into the subroutine, either by positional arguments or by named parameters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To avoid the warning, you can enclose the new variable declaration, and the code that uses it, inside curly braces (`{...}`) and create a new scope.

```
my $var = 3;
print "$var\n";

{    
    my $var = 4;
    print "$var\n";
}
```

Comment: that works totally fine... but i’d wish you also added a huge warning that the the 2nd $var does is no longer available after the closing `}`. and also that after the closing `}` the first $var comes back in place and $var has the value as before... ‘3’. truly this answers is not an answer i would recommend for someone that apperntly is new to Perl and seemingly is not aware of things like ‘scope’ and how to write subroutines. the answer does indeed meet the needs asked, but is far from complete and unsuitable for novice Perl programmer

Comment: @vanHoesel I think it is better to put the first chunk in separate braces as well. Then there wouldn't be any `$var` that "comes back" to confuse me.

Comment: although that would be totally valid to do, it's something i would rather avoid. creating 'scope' all over the place to fix one other problem is not really a good way to solve it. the only thing you were running into is the redeclaration message. That could have been fixed with changing the part where you caused it `undef $var; my $var = 4;` .... just skip the really unnecessary and do the following `$var = 4`. It is really totally fine to do `my $var;` somewhere upwards in the block of code and then lateron assign values to it when needed, just before your `print`.

Comment: having said that, i usually dislike re-use of variables or giving them different meanings or context. i prefer variables with a name that describes what the content is about. `$var` is not one of them. Creating a new variable is not a sin.

Comment: Really and truly, refactoring the code, using subroutines would be a good thing to start working on, but that would require more than the seven lines of code you showed.